# Can we have related or hottest from the non-meta site on the sidebar? (or at least a link somewhere?)

Tags: feature-request

I have noticed that on.SE sites, there is a related meta discussion on the sidebar. I have noticed the meta..SE does not have related pointing back to the original site.

I think it might be a good feature, since it helps me keep track of whats happeneing with meta, but constantly find myself having to re-type in the address bar the non-meta site when I want to go back.

It would just make it easier to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click `parent` in the topbar to return to the site.